# sitemesh and struts2 filter priority issue with jetty container?

Tags: struts2, jetty, sitemesh

I am trying to add sitemesh with Struts 2 , but there is this issue of filter priority coming. When I add **Struts first and then Sitemesh** as :

```
 <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>

     <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>


     <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Struts tags works like  but decorator doesn't work with Jetty
 **(Works fine in tomcat)** 
 
If I reverse and put sitemesh first, then decorator work but there comes error with struts2 tags. **(Both Jetty and Tomcat)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it's suggested configuration as below which is mentioned at [Struts SiteMesh Plugin homepage](https://struts.apache.org/docs/sitemesh-plugin.html)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```